# Replacing youtube image placeholders to video

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, youtube, click

I have a jquery function which replaces a Link within two values with an image for e.g

```
<div class="comment">
[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1hf4B5pyjQ&feature=grec_index[/youtube]
random text
</div>
```

will be output as

```
<div class="comment"><img width="420" height="315" src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/T1hf4B5pyjQ/hqdefault.jpg"></img>
random text
</div>
```

with this function below

```
var youtubeTag = /\[youtube]https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com|\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=|v\/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)([a-zA-Z&=;_+0-9*#-]*?)\[\/youtube]/,
    youtubeHTML = '<img width="420" height="315" src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/$1/hqdefault.jpg"></img>';
$(".comment").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(youtubeTag, youtubeHTML))
});
```

what I'm trying to do is onclicking the image replace youtubeHTML with youtubeIFRAME i have tried this below or check it out on JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/yusaf/uLTzw/28/

```
var youtubeTag = /\[youtube]https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com|\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=|v\/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)([a-zA-Z&=;_+0-9*#-]*?)\[\/youtube]/,
    youtubeHTML = '<img width="420" height="315" src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/$1/hqdefault.jpg"></img>';
    youtubeIFRAME = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$(".comment").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(youtubeTag, youtubeHTML))
});

$("img").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(youtubeHTML, youtubeIFRAME))
});
```

Comment: Why are you encapsulating the image with 2 divs? You can style your imgs with `margin` and use also `display: block`.

Comment: true, it was temporary it will be further improved once i get  a solution im really stuck on what to do ive tried alot of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$1` part inside `youtubeHTML` which is not allowing the handler to replace the HTML correctly.

One quick solution is to use `data` attribute on `youtubeHTML` and store the link also there. Then simply replace the `$1` inside the `youtubeIFRAME` with the value of that `data` attribute.

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/uLTzw/49/) is the snippet.

```
var youtubeTag = /\[youtube]https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com|\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=|v\/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)([a-zA-Z&=;_+0-9*#-]*?)\[\/youtube]/;
var youtubeHTML = '<img width="420" data-address="$1" height="315" class="youtube" src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/$1/hqdefault.jpg"></img>';
var youtubeIFRAME = '<iframe width="420" height="315" class="youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

$(".comment").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(youtubeTag, youtubeHTML));
});

$("img.youtube").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);   
    $this.replaceWith(youtubeIFRAME.replace("$1", $this.attr("data-address")));
});
```

*EDIT:* In case anyone is interested in a way how to write some kind of short "click here" text over the placeholder images have a look **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/Y8TG7/)**.

Comment: is there a way of returning from the Iframe back to the image placeholder i have tried but i can't seem to get it right. for eg http://jsfiddle.net/yusaf/uLTzw/161/

Comment: @Yusaf: You have a few errors there. **1)** `.closevid` spans don't exists at the time you are trying to append click handlers. **2)**  `$this` in `.closevid` is referencing to `span` and not to `iframe`. **3)** `replace(youtubeHTML, youtubeIFRAME)` won't do anything because the HTML part contains chars `$1` which cannot be found in HTML. Try **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/uLTzw/163/)** ugly solution :).

Comment: You have been really helpful and i am stuck with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378575/get-string-between-two-strings-using-jquery could you help me find a solution?