# get string between two strings using jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes, image, extract, src

If I have this HTML

```
<div class="comment-body">
[img]http://topnews.net.nz/images/YouTube-3.jpg[/img] random text here
</div>

<div class="comment-body">
[img]http://blog.brightcove.com/sites/all/uploads/FACEBOOK%20ICON.png[/img] random text here
</div>
```

how using jquery can I extract the value between `[img]` and `[/img]` and set it as a variable `data-src2=""` within an `<img>` element giving

```
<div class="comment-body">
<img src="samesrc" class="commentimg" data-src2="http://topnews.net.nz/images/YouTube-3.jpg"/> random text here
</div>

<div class="comment-body">
<img src="samesrc" class="commentimg" data-src2="http://blog.brightcove.com/sites/all/uploads/FACEBOOK%20ICON.png"/> random text here
</div>
```

I don't have anything to give for what I have tried as I don't have a clue how to extract the value between `[img]` and `[/img]`

but overall **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/yusaf/zy5j8/35/)** is what I'm trying to achieve if it doesn't make sense!

Comment: No need for jQuery, just a plain jane regex!

Comment: So, you want a BBCode parser?

Comment: @Rocket something to that effect yes, it makes things easier!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some effort, please. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843320/any-good-javascript-bbcode-parser

Comment: I wish I could upvote a comment 10 times

Comment: I have looked over the net and i can promise that, search it i can't find anything but stuff for php and c++ which i don't know.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL i only searched BBcode when it was mentioned by Rocket sorry

Comment: In your example output you actually removed anything else in the `div`. Is this what you want to accomplish or just a mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tested and now works (original version didn't iterate through all `.comment-body` elements, or find the `substring()` properly):

```
var divString, imgString;
$('.comment-body').each(
    function(){
        divString = $(this).text();
        imgString = divString.substring(divString.indexOf('[img]') + 5,divString.indexOf('[/img]'));
        console.log(imgString);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kYK7e/).

---

**Edited** because I got a little bit bored, and so turned the above into a more-generic function:

```
function findStringBetween(elem,bbTagStart,bbTagClose){
    var tag = bbTagStart;

    function impliedEndTag(tag){
        var impliedEnd = tag.replace(tag.substring(0,1),tag.substring(0,1) + '/');
        return impliedEnd;
    }

    var endTag = bbTagClose || impliedEndTag(tag);

    var divString = $(elem).text();
    var tagString = divString.substring(divString.indexOf('[img]') + tag.length,divString.indexOf('[/img'));
    return tagString;
}
$('.comment-body').each(
    function(){
        /* call with two, or three arguments (the third is the optional 'bbTagClose':
            1. elem = this, the DOM node,
            2. '[img]' = whatever bbCode thing you want to use (I'm not sure what's available),
            3. 'bbTagClose' = the end tag of the bbCode, assuming that the end-tag is the same as
                the opening tag, except with a '/' as the second character, the impliedEndTag() function
                will take care of it for you.
        */
        var elemString = findStringBetween(this,'[img]');
        $(this).replaceWith('<img src="' + elemString + '" class="commentimg" data-src2="'+ elemString +'"/>');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kYK7e/24/).

---

**Edited** following further questions from OP (in comments, below):

> ...the function adds an '' to every div with the class comment-body how can i only have the code applied to comment-body elements that contain [img]image src here[/img]

I've added a couple of sanity-checks, to ensure that the function returns false when the defined tag isn't found:

```
function findStringBetween(elem,bbTagStart,bbTagClose){
    var tag = bbTagStart;

    function impliedEndTag(tag){
        var impliedEnd = tag.replace(tag.substring(0,1),tag.substring(0,1) + '/');
        return impliedEnd;
    }

    var endTag = bbTagClose || impliedEndTag(tag);
    var divString = $(elem).text().trim(); // added .trim() to remove white-spaces

    if (divString.indexOf(tag) != -1){ // makes sure that the tag is within the string
        var tagString = divString.substring(divString.indexOf('[img]') + tag.length,divString.indexOf('[/img'));
        return tagString;
    }
    else { // if the tag variable is not within the string the function returns false
        return false;
    }
}
$('.comment-body').each(
    function(){
        /* call with two, or three arguments (the third is the optional 'bbTagClose':
            1. elem = this, the DOM node,
            2. '[img]' = whatever bbCode thing you want to use (I'm not sure what's available),
            3. 'bbTagClose' = the end tag of the bbCode, assuming that the end-tag is the same as
                the opening tag, except with a '/' as the second character, the impliedEndTag() function
                will take care of it for you.
        */
       var imgLink = findStringBetween(this,'[img]');
        if (imgLink){ // only if a value is set to the variable imgLink will the following occur
            $(this).replaceWith('<img src="' + imgLink + '" class="commentimg" data-src2="'+ imgLink+'"/>');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kYK7e/46/).

---

**Edited** in response to further question from OP (in comments, below):

> [Is] there a way of preventing it from removing the text in this example 'random text here'[?]

Yes, you can `.append()`, or `.prepend()` the image into the element, after first updating the text of the `div`, in the following code I've removed the `[img]...[/img]` string, to leave *just* the other text, inserted that text into the `.comment-body` element and then appended the `img` to that, instead of using `replaceWith()`:

```
function findStringBetween(elem,bbTagStart,bbTagClose){
    var tag = bbTagStart;

    function impliedEndTag(tag){
        var impliedEnd = tag.replace(tag.substring(0,1),tag.substring(0,1) + '/');
        return impliedEnd;
    }

    var endTag = bbTagClose || impliedEndTag(tag);
    var divString = $(elem).text().trim();

    if (divString.indexOf(tag) != -1){
        var elemInfo = [];
        elemInfo.imgString = divString.substring(divString.indexOf(tag) + tag.length,divString.indexOf(endTag));
        elemInfo.text = divString.replace(tag + elemInfo.imgString + endTag, '');
        return elemInfo;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
$('.comment-body').each(
    function(){
        /* call with two, or three arguments (the third is the optional 'bbTagClose':
            1. elem = this, the DOM node,
            2. '[img]' = whatever bbCode thing you want to use (I'm not sure what's available),
            3. 'bbTagClose' = the end tag of the bbCode, assuming that the end-tag is the same as
                the opening tag, except with a '/' as the second character, the impliedEndTag() function
                will take care of it for you.
        */
       var elemInfo = findStringBetween(this,'[img]');
        if (elemInfo.imgString){
            // or .prepend() if you prefer
            $(this).text(elemInfo.text).append('<img src="' + elemInfo.imgString + '" class="commentimg" data-src2="'+ elemInfo.imgString +'"/>');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kYK7e/75/).

---

References:

- jQuery stuff:

  - [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend).
  - [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- JavaScript (all at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)'s [JavaScript documentation resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript):

  - [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length).
  - [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
  - [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).
  - [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Comment: Sir, I don't know what in the _world_ you are talking about. All _I_ saw was a gust of wind.

Comment: I have tried http://jsfiddle.net/yusaf/kYK7e/3/ it wont work could i please have a bit of guidance.please.

Comment: I don't want to be fussy, but 'it wont work' isn't a great bug-report. In what way does it not work?

Comment: @Yusaf: David's code is working very well (+1 :o) ). You just need to use `tagString` to create the `<img>` elements (like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/kYK7e/14/)).

Comment: @dzejkej, thanks for amending the function to actually return the variable...I *knew* there was something left that I'd meant to do before posting it. Have a hearty, and grateful, +1 for your comment, sir! =) *Edited your amendments in* (Albeit I chose to replace with the image, rather than retain the `samesrc`...)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kYK7e/34/ the function adds an '<img>' to every div with the class comment-body how can i only have the code applied to comment-body elements that contain [img]image src here[/img]

Comment: @Yusaf, see the updated answer; the final code block should work as you require.

Comment: is there a way of preventing it from removing the text in this example 'random text here'

Comment: *Note to readers*: In case your code is calling `findStringBetween()` often, consider defining function `impliedEndTag()` outside of the `findStringBetween()`. When a function contains another function then everytime the "parent" function is called its "children" functions are created. So calling `findStringBetween()` 100 times means that `impliedEndTag()` is created 100 times. See **[this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/stop-nesting-functions-but-not-all-of-them/)**.

Comment: Yusaf, yes: see the latest edit and posted JS Fiddle. @dzejkej: good point; I'd forgotten about that. =/

Comment: I promise you i have very little knowledge of jquery just the basics such as addclass removeclass etc, that is why i didn't try something if i had the knowledge on where to start i would have as you'll see in other more basic questions that i have asked but if you want to see what i was trying to achieve the whole time i have a link here  http://jsfiddle.net/5RcEh/2/ it's almost in some ways similar to tumblr iamge posts on the dashboard

Comment: I've added some reference materials to the end of the post, for you to read through. It can take a while to get comfortable with JavaScript, or even jQuery. Just ask the questions you have (once you've *tried* to research them) and, when you're able, start answering. I don't have time to look at your Fiddle now, but I'll try to remember to look tomorrow, after work. =)

Comment: @DavidThomas Great work, David! Nice extra bonus with all those reference materials :).

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry to be a bug but what if there is more than 1 [img][/img] in a comment-body element i have tried .each for a funtion but it wont work http://jsfiddle.net/kYK7e/89/

Answer (score 2):

Alternative answer to the one wrote by *David Thomas*.

Another way how to implement this code is to use regular expressions.

```
// inputText - input text that contains tags
// tagName - name of the tag we want to replace
// tagReplace - replacement for the tag, "$1" will get replaced by content of the tag
function replaceText(inputText, tagName, tagReplace) {
  var regExp = new RegExp('\\[' + tagName+ '\\]([^\\[]*)\\[\/' + tagName + '\\]', 'g');
  return inputText.replace(regExp, tagReplace);
}

$('.comment-body').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var replacedText = replaceText($this.text(), 'img', '<img src="$1" \/>');
  $this.html(replacedText);
});
```

This implementation will also replace multiple tags within the comment.

See **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/x7N7S/)** code snippet.

**Note 1:**

When implementing this code in real environment please consider pre-creating regular expression for all handled tag names outside `replaceText()` so `regExp` won't be created everytime `replaceText()` is called.

**Note 2:**

To get the exact output as in the question change:

```
  var replacedText = replaceText($this.text(), 'img', '<img src="$1" \/>');
```

to

```
  var replacedText = replaceText($this.text(), 'img', '<img src="samesrc" class="commentimg" data-src2="$1" \/>');
```

Comment: how can you alter this so it works alongside the YouTube tags i have because they also use $1 http://jsfiddle.net/x7N7S/11/

Comment: @Yusaf: I recommend you to study a bit and experiment with the code so you will be able to modify it by yourself. If you will still have trouble, **create a new question**. Use comments only to discuss the concrete answer for a concrete question and not for other purposes. FYI: Code in my answer will put whole youtube link to `$1`. To solve your issue you need to either modify the regexp to extract only the `?watch=` part and not youtube link or insert only `?watch=thisPart` between the tags (more general solution): see **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/Y8TG7/11/)**.

Comment: thankyou, i have tried stuff but they're useless, i will post links for failures from now, sorry.

Comment: @Yusaf: Glad to help :). Sorry if it sounded rude, but creating a question helps other people to find same problems more easily, people helping you have better tools (like code blocks, ability to edit after more than 5 minutes, etc.) and they can get some extra rep as a bonus :).

Comment: I have created a solution to the [youtube][/youtube] and [img][/img] problem i was having, dzejkej and David Thomas you have been brilliant thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

This function finds any given bbcodes in any string and if you want, you can configure it for replacing or extract content as array from those bbcodes.

```
//search str 
var search_str = "I love this [img]question.png[/img] Flowers, and [img]answer_1-1.png[/img] you say is that [img]answer_2-1.png[/img] good Point."
//using example
var str = bbcode_search_and_replace($('#search_str').text(),"[img]","[/img]");
$('#search_str').html(str);

function bbcode_search_and_replace(search_str, bb_opening_tag, bb_closing_tag) {
            //search str length
           var sLength = String(search_str).length;
           //bbcode opening tag length
           var fPart_length = String(bb_opening_tag).length;
           //bbcode closing tag length
           var ePart_length = String(bb_closing_tag).length;
           //position index for opening tag 
           var start_idx = 0;
           //position index for closing tag 
           var end_idx = 0; 
           //searching index for opening tag
           var pos_sIdx = 0;
           //position index for closing tag
           var pos_eIdx = 0;
           //var replacement = '[image]';
           var arr = [];
           var idx = 0;           

           //loop
           while(start_idx !== -1) {
               arr[idx] = {};                  

               start_idx = String(search_str).indexOf(bb_opening_tag,pos_sIdx);
               //check for ending
               if(start_idx === -1) {
                   //if exist, last str after closing tag
                   if(idx > 0) arr[idx]['str'] = search_str.substring(pos_sIdx);
                   console.log("arr[idx]['str'] = " + arr[idx]['str']);
                   break;
               }
               //end position index
               pos_eIdx = start_idx + fPart_length;
               end_idx = String(search_str).indexOf(bb_closing_tag,pos_eIdx);                   
               //save str inside bbtags
               arr[idx]['str'] = search_str.substring(pos_sIdx, start_idx);
               console.log("arr[idx]['str'] = " + arr[idx]['str']);
               arr[idx]['src'] =  "<img src = 'img/" + search_str.substring(start_idx + fPart_length, end_idx) + "' />";
               console.log("arr[idx]['src'] = " + arr[idx]['src']);
               arr[idx]['pos_start'] = start_idx + fPart_length;
               arr[idx]['pos_end'] = end_idx;                                

               //Update array and start pos indexes
               idx++;
               pos_sIdx = end_idx + ePart_length;                
          }

           var k = 0;
           var str = "";
           while(k < arr.length) {
               if(arr[k]['src'] === undefined) arr[k]['src'] = "";
               str += arr[k]['str'] + arr[k]['src'];
               k++;
           }

           return str;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript match() function, very easy to use

Like if you have a string **"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."**

& you need the text just between "quick" and "lazy"

Use below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myStr = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
   var subStr = myStr.match("quick(.*)lazy");
   alert(subStr[1]);
</script>
```

Hope it helps !!